# Поиск в базе данных PHP

Tags: php, mysql

В БД есть такая таблица…
Не получается реализовать поиск по таблице.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно что бы при выполнении скрипта он считывал `UNIX_GMT` и сверял со временем на сервере, если время сервера в формате `UNIX` больше чем `UNIX` в базе данных 
то он подставлял бы данные из `Group_ID` и `Wall_ID` в:

```
$wd->send($Wall_ID, $Group_ID, $Standalone_Token);
```

После успешного выполнения он бы убирал из таблицы БД строку над которой проводились манипуляции...

Весь скрипт будет в `cron` задачах и будет проверятся через определенный промежуток времени.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь...

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так

```
select * from MyTable where  Now() > date
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы что какие действия тут происходят?

Comment: @ТимофейКучербаев я не проч все расписать, но вам рекомендую задать простой вопрос в яндексе "php выбрать из базы все больше текущей даты" прям первые три строчки дадут вам исчервывающий ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT `ID`, `Group_ID`, `Wall_ID` FROM `уот_такая_таблица` WHERE `UNIX_GMT` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$wd->send($result['Wall_ID'], $result['Group_ID'], $Standalone_Token);

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `уот_такая_таблица` WHERE `ID` = {$result['ID']}");
}
```